# SQL bug or something else?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, get

I have made a simple amateur component in Joomla...

In it there is a select>option drop-down list, which add parameters to the URL.

The problem was that it did not worked with 1.1 value and it works with a 1.5 value.

A friend of mine fixed the problem, but I want to know why it happened

Original Query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE Power='".$_GET["Power"]."' AND Poles='".$_GET["Poles"]."'";
```

The new working query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE Power=".floatval($_GET["Power"])." AND Poles='".$_GET["Poles"]."'";
```

Comment: Your queries are prone to SQL injection attacks. This is a security risk. See http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php for more info.

Comment: What should I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Joomla, you should really be sticking to Joomla's coding standards and methods for everything, this includes database queries:

https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

You should also be using `JInput` instead of `$_POST` or `$_GET` calls:

http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Looking at your query, it should looking something like this:

```
$db    = JFactory::getDbo();
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$power = $input->get('Power', '', 'RAW');
$polls = $input->get('Pols', '', 'RAW');

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->qn(array('*')))
      ->from($db->qn('#__table'))
      ->where($db->qn('Power') . ' = ' . $db->q($power), 'AND')
      ->where($db->qn('Polls') . ' = ' . $db->q($polls));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

// Do what you want with the $results object
```

Using this means that column names and data values are escaped properly and you've not left with SQL vulnerabilities as @skidr0w mentioned.

**Note:** `#__` is the database table prefix, assuming you've followed this approach. If not, simply replace `#__table` with the full name of your table

Comment: What a great explanation! 
Thank you very much for the patience!

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in public_html/components/com_helloworld/views/dsql/tmpl/default.php on line 4

Comment: @TeodorBochev - Oops, sorry. Updated my answer

Comment: my database is mysite_mydatabase, my joomla database is mysite_joomla.

How can I access it? 

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should put all the tables inside the Joomla database. Don't use separate databases. Once done, `$db = JFactory::getDbo();` will take care of the connection for you.

Comment: My Joomla website DB is

mysite_2
I created a table inside it

mysite_2 »Table: TABLE 2
How should I access it?

$query->select($db->qn(array('*')))
      ->from($db->qn('**WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?**'))

Comment: Does this database table use the same prefix as all other tables? For example, Joomla tables will all have the same prefix, like: `jos_extensions, jos_modules, jos_menus` etc (`jos_` is the prefix in this example). So make sure your database table uses this same prefix. Once done, you can use `->from($db->qn('#__2'))`

Answer (score 0):

The table column Power is of type float or double. In your first query you try to insert a string value. The second query inserts the correct float by first casting the request value to float and removing the quotes around the value.

By the way, you sould never ever use unfiltered user-input (such as $_GET values) in a sql query.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, after several days I found that the problem and the solution were simpler.

Just removing the '-sign solved the problem

```
 Power='".$_GET["Power"]."'
```

with

```
 Power=".$_GET["Power"]."
```

Regards